# Does FTL signaling allow signaling in the past at the cost of arbitrary precision?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light

In a recent paper (http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-30870-3_53#page-1), G. Szekely and P.Nemeti wrote the following.
Let us consider two reference frames *A* and *B* initially, at event I, at rest w.r.t. each other. *B* is then set in
uniformly accelerated motion w.r.t. *A*.  There would be 
an event *O* on *A*-worldline such that it would satisfy the three following properties :

1. Any event *E* on *B*-worldline would be simultaneous with *O* in the inertial referentiel comoving with *B*.
2. Let us fix an event *M* on *A-wordline that is posterior to *O* according to *A*. If supraluminal signaling were possible, *B* could send a signal to *A* that would reach it between *O* and *M* from any point on its worldline, no matter how far in spacetime.
3. As the distance in spacetime between *A* and *B* becomes larger, the sender will have to compute the speed of the faster-than-light signal with greater and greater accuracy to reach *A* between *O* and *M*.

Are these three properties (especially #3) actually verified by superluminal signals in Special Relativity?

Comment: arXiv version is here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1773